# How can I display a variable content in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables

[*It's already my 9th day of learning how to code! #excitement*](http://atechkat.blogspot.com)

Let's say I have a title

```
<h1 id="title">TEST </h1>
```

And I have the variable

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    var content=$("#title).html();
</script>
```

How do I now get the var content displayed in let's say a new paragraph?
  I was trying something like this:

```
<p id="test">  <p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#test").html(content);
    </script>
```

Thanks!

PS: I've seen things using "Element.innerHTML", but that didn't seem to really fit my problem, or I just didn'T get it. The question asker didn't provide an example.

Comment: `#title` should be `.title`, as it is a class but you are using it as an id. and your quotes are not closing properly.  `var content=$(".title").html();`

Comment: @MuhammadUsman don't forget mention the typo

Comment: # is used with id and (.) with class. Ins your case title is a class and test is and id so instead of #title use .title to get the content.

Comment: #congrats #excitement

Comment: or in headder tag <h1 class="title">TEST </h1> change class="title" to id="title"

Comment: @Manish True! Thanks. It's just a typo here though. In my file I did use "id " in both cases and therefore #. It still doesn't work.

Comment: I would recommend learning the basics of pure javascript before learning how to use a javascript plugin like jQuery. This will help give you a better understanding of how things function. I would also recommend you read the jQuery documentation as this will explain the different methods they have to offer. Example Target is `#` - Target class `.`

Comment: Have a look at the answer posted by Bharat. the only thing is that he has not used a variable to store the content.

Comment: @atechkat don't mess up your question code changing class with id. Answer above already work if you don't change it. Moreover you can't refer to mutiple dom elements using same id!

Answer (score 4):

Simple way you can do this, see below code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#test").text($(".title").html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>

<h1 class="title">TEST </h1>
<p id="test">  <p>
```

Comment: Thanks. But what I am trying to accomplish is to show in what a variable is holding.
So while this is generally helpful, it doesn't do anything with a var.
How can I display the content of `var=x` as normal text in e.g. a `<p>`?

Comment: @atechkat Not hard thing, what you have to do is if you want to place text in `<p>` then just use  `$("#test").text(X);` and if you want to place html then just use  `$("#test").html(X);` but make sure content for `X` you get proper with using correct `selector`